# At startup on windows 7, a box opens with the title communicator.exe and it says: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)

Tags: windows-7, startup, office-communicator

It just opens everytime I turn on my laptop. Does anyone know what it is and how to stop it showing up on startup? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but your question is off-topic here, but I believe microsoft is favouring Skype now over communicator...

Comment: As stated by the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) I don't see anything related to writing software and /or code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try finding communicator.exe using "msconfig" command and then uncheck it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I found out it was a part of Lync. :D